# Avoiding Assigning Classes to Multiple Variables

Tags: python, class, variables

I would like to make a program where I have multiple times I use a class. I don't want to have to create tons of variables such as through a11=animal() a12=animal(). I also would prefer not to have to have so many variables to manage even if they are created by an exec() in a loop. Is there any way to assign classes to dictionary key, list places, or use another easy way to manage them. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you mean *instances* of a class. You can put those instances in whatever data structure you want.

Comment: You can store class instances in a container such as a `list` named `animals`. That way their "names" would become indices: e.g. `animals[0]` and `animals[42]`. You should not be using `exec` to dynamically create variables. See [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html) and [_Keep data out of your variable names_](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should have tried it in the coding environment I usually work in first. I appreciate the swift replies. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create instances of classes with any data structure. For example:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    #Animal() is a class you've defined elsewhere
    my_list.append(Animal())
```

Now the my_list variable should contain 9 instances of your Animal class

You also assign these to a dictionary, if that is what you want.